# BS4: removing <a> tags

Tags: python, html, parsing, beautifulsoup, html-parsing

I'm using BeautifulSoup 4, I have below HTML:

```
<tr>
  <td>London <a href="/company/mcrt/5" target="_blank">10 vol</a> 54 page</td>
</tr>
```

I'm trying to remove just the "a" tag and keep the text inside, like this:

```
<tr>
  <td>London 10 vol 54 page</td>
</tr>
```

Is there any way to do it with bs4?

Comment: Of course it's possible, what have you tried? What problems are you encountering? Please provide the code you're having problems with

Comment: I found the .text method, which removes all tags and returns "London 10 vol 54 page". but I don't want to remove the <tr><td> tags.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are searching for [`.unwrap()`](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#unwrap) method:

```
txt = '''<tr>
  <td>London <a href="/company/mcrt/5" target="_blank">10 vol</a> 54 page</td>
</tr>'''

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

soup = BeautifulSoup(txt, 'html.parser')

soup.a.unwrap()

print(soup)
```

Prints:

```
<tr>
<td>London 10 vol 54 page</td>
</tr>
```